# is every function defined on natural numbers considered a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I wonder if every function that operates over the set of natural numbers (or its finite subset ranging from $1$ to $k$) is considered a sequence?

It seems to me that the answer is yes, at least when one looks at the common definition of a sequence:

$$a: \mathbb{J} \to X$$
where: $\mathbb{J}$ is either $\mathbb{N}$ or $\{1, 2,..., k\}$

Comment: A function  such as described in OP is a standard way of denoting a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"We define and as "sequence" or "infinite sequence" any function :f : $ \mathbb N \rightarrow A, A \subseteq \mathbb R$. We also define as "finite sequence"  any function : $f : (1,2,..,n)\rightarrow A, A \subseteq \mathbb R $." Note that $(1,2,...,n)$ is a set $a \subseteq \mathbb N$.

Comment: So it seems to me from your answer that yes, every function that maps naturals number to real numbers (or its ordered subset from 1 to k) is a sequence. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @sztal For all intents and purposes the terms may be used interchangably

Comment: What it was mentioned right before me!

Comment: This is the precise definition in mathematical journals and books.

Comment: Note that your two uses of $A \in \mathbb{R}$ should be $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Yep corrected it, where's my mind at ?

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone for the disambiguation, since this issue was quite confusing for me. Now the world is a bit simpler.

Answer (score -6):

From [WolframMathWorld on Sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sequence.html):

> A sequence is an ordered set of mathematical objects.

From [WolframMathWorld on ordered set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrderedSet.html):

> [An ordered set is a]n ambiguous term which is sometimes used to mean a partially ordered set and sometimes to mean a totally ordered set.

And I will not quote [WolframMathWorld on totally ordered set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotallyOrderedSet.html).

---

However, there is a site of integer sequence, called the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) (On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences), which have sequences like this:

[A000005](http://oeis.org/A000005) (the number of divisors of $n$):

> 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 6, 2, 4, ...

---

TL;DR:

- From WolframMathWorld: the answer is **no**. A sequence must be increasing.
- However, the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) (On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences) also record non-increasing sequences.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, and largely does not address the question.  It is not true that every sequence must be increasing.

Comment: @vadim123 Why is the answer incorrect?

Comment: Also, mathworld is not a dictionary.  You can't just look up each term in it, in sequence, and glue it all together.

Comment: Here is a counter example: sequence defined as (-1)^n

Comment: @sztal I am merely quoting WolframMathWorld.

Comment: Once again, it is in OEIS as [A033999](http://oeis.org/A033999).

Comment: I must say that the explanation on mathworls is really totally misleading.

Comment: When you cited Wolfram you looked up totally ordered set, rather than the term sequence asked about in the posted question.